# Bind C-e C-j and C-a C-o TAB to single key, aka insert and jump to newline

Tags: key-bindings, commands, newlines

C-e C-j will insert a newline below and jump to it indented.
C-a C-o TAB will insert a newline above and jump to it indented.

Is there a single bind to these or where/how should I bind these commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always check what function some keys are bound to using `C-h k`. For example, if we type `C-h k C-e`, we see that it is bound to `(move-end-of-line ARG)`; similarly, `C-j` is bound to `(newline-and-indent)`.

In this case, it turns out that `C-e C-j` is a sequence of two commands rather than a single thing. (The same with `C-a C-o TAB`.) To bind this to a single key, we first have to wrap it in a function. You can define this function in your `.emacs` file:

```
(defun my-newline-below ()
  "Insert a newline below and jump to it indented."
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line nil)
  (newline-and-indent))
```

All this function does is run the two commands we found. The string on top is just some documentation, and `(interactive)` is needed so that you can bind it to a key (or call it directly from `M-x`). `move-end-of-line` takes an argument, so we just pass in `nil` to get the default behavior. Happily, the output of `C-h k` tells us we can do this, so we don't have to guess what `ARG` is for.

Now we can just globally set this to some key:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-j") 'my-newline-below)
```

And voilà: the first command you wanted, bound to `C-M-j`. Now you can do the second one the same way, which is a great exercise to learn how to define your own custom commands like this.

Comment: Great!, can you also suggest me sample mappings for these commands, eg. what do you use @TikhonJelvis?

Comment: @user3995789: Euh, that's actually pretty tricky. I don't use those particular commands myself, and have a bunch of custom mappings already. In fact, looking at it, `C-M-j` is already bound to something, it's just something I don't use. You'll have to look around for some free keybindings on your own setup; traditionally, ones in the form `C-c a` where `a` can be any letter are reserved for your customizations, but I've found they're a bit awkward to type.